# React Как в create react app добавить предзагрузку изображений?

Tags: reactjs

Подскажи, пожалуйста как в React добавлять предзагрузку? Что-то по типу

```
<head>
..
..
<link rel="preload" href="<your_image_source_here>" as="image">
...
</head>
```

вижу только стандартный файл `index.js` но не знаю как достучаться до `<head>`

Comment: в папке public есть index.html

Comment: Спасибо, а ещё вопрос. Если в компонент отдается скажем изображение с именем `chest.svg`, но при инспектировании в  DevTools я наблюдаю уже chest.b8980a5d.svg (с добавленной солью), будет ли то изображение которое я отдам как `<link rel="preload" href="https://mysite.com/chest.svg" as="image">` определено браузером как копия изображения и закешировано как копия ?